# Uninstalling GNS3 installed from source

Tags: 14.04, networking

i installed GNS3 from source be executing 'setup.py install'. Now i wonder how to remove it, as there is no uninstall option in setup.py. I can do a dry run to see which files are created so as to manually remove them, but they are way too much. 
Any Easy way to accomplish this feat?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed your python application with a command line:

```
python setup.py install
```

And if the author did not provide an uninstall script.

You can try the following commands to uninstall it:

```
sudo -i
python setup.py install --record installed.txt
cat installed.txt | xargs rm -rf
```

If this does not work for you, you can try

Install the application checkinstall:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install checkinstall
```

Below run

```
sudo -i
checkinstall python setup.py install
```

Checkinstall created for you a file.deb, and you can remove it with:

```
sudo -i
dpkg -r Name_of_package
```

Comment: Thanks a lot kyodake, checkinstall was precisely what i needed. That solves my problem.